# "Access denied" Error on clicking user/reset link

Tags: users, 9

I am a Drupal newbie, so pardon any errors in my question. In my D9 site I am using password policy module to set password policy rules. When I hit "Reset password" I get a one-time link to my email. Upon clicking the link, it shows "Access Denied"-You are not authorized to access this page error. The log shows below error message:

```
"Path: /user/reset/10. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: in Drupal\user\Controller\UserController->getResetPassForm() (line 186 of /var/www/html/web/core/modules/user/src/Controller/UserController.php)."
```

Reset password link is as below:

```
https://mysitedomain/user/reset/10/1644339844/Xglx63gun5qPwmUzv2BEBZPLBUmH-eW0ekVEndy4_1M
```

Any help on how this can be fixed? The user I'm trying to reset the password is active.

Comment: If you uninstall the Password Policy module, do the links work?  (Are you sure this is caused by the Password Policy module?)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by removing samesite attribute from php.ini. I had it set as "Strict" to comply with OWASP requirements. But Strict means that if you click on a link on foo.org that goes to drupal.org, then you would *not* send the session cookie and you would not be logged in. Which is why I was getting to see "Access Denied" errors constantly.

Comment: Ah, yes, Drupal 8/9 fails to set `SameSite` on session cookies; [the core bug report for this is here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3150614).